# Python equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string, for getting strings safely into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a Python equivalent of PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string`?

I'm trying to insert some strings into a MySQL db direct from Python, and keep getting tripped up by quotes in the strings.

```
mysql_string = "INSERT INTO candidate (name, address) VALUES  " 
for k, v in v_dict.iteritems():
    mysql_string += " ('" + v_dict['name'] + "', '" + v_dict['address'] + "'), "
mysql_string += ";"
cursor.execute(mysql_string)
```

I've tried `re.escape()` but that escapes every non-alphanumeric character in the strings, which isn't what I need - I just need to escape single quotes in this instance (plus more generally anything else that might trip up MySQL).

Could do this manually I guess, but is there a smarter way to do it in Python?

Comment: Do you have some sort of CSV file that you are using python to insert into a MySQL database? And you're using `import csv` to get dictionaries for each row of data? If so, you should look up the MySQL bulk insert utility. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Yeah - don't even ask. I host with Webfaction and they don't support mysqlimport :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape string Python for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you are using mysql-python, just try

```
MySQLdb.escape_string(SQL)
```

Example

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.escape_string("'")
"\\'"
```

Comment: Thought it would be something simple. Thanks!

Comment: -1 This is the wrong answers in several ways. The OP would be better off using cursor.executemany() or using a bulk load tool if he is starting from a csv file.

Comment: You may check [MySQLdb's documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#id5). its exactly an equivalent of `mysql_real_escape_string`. I know, *My* answer did not cover all, but its not wrong. But ok, you could **disagree**.

Comment: @you actually this is the answer that worked for me

Answer (score 15):

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO candidate (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)',
                   [(v_dict['name'], v_dict['address'])] * len(v_dict))
```

should do what your code appears to attempt -- inserting the **same** identical values N times (you're looping on `v_dict.iteritems()` but completely ignoring the loop variables, and instad just  reusing those specific two values from `v_dict` each and every time).  Of course if you mean something completely different the second line will need to be changed accordingly, but the key idea anyway is to use placeholders, not string formatting, for such tasks.

Comment: Alex is right: using executemany() this way avoids the formatting issues and all the possibilities for incorrect SQL. And @AP257 you are doing something crazy with your dictionary, as Alex intimates.

Comment: I had same isue, your method is easiest but with  """triple double quotes"""  you can avoid many bugs. 

`cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO candidate (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)""",
                   [(v_dict['name'], v_dict['address'])] * len(v_dict))`

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a Python equivalent of PHP's mysql_real_escape_string?

Yes, it's `escape_string` on the database **connection** object.

**Not** `escape_string` on the `MySQLdb` module, which is equivalent to `mysql_escape_string` in PHP, and has the same potential vulnerability with multibyte character sets. You shouldn't use `MySQLdb.escape_string`.

In any case, you are much better off using parameterised queries as in Alex's answer. This makes it easier to port to other databases (it's part of the DB-API standard, which `escape_string` is not), and it's generally more convenient. (And much more convenient than parameterisation is in PHP.)

Comment: I'm getting `Error writing to database: 'CMySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'escape_string'`

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you just need to use executemany method of the cursor.

```
mysql_string = "INSERT INTO candidate (name, address) VALUES  (%s,%s);"
cursor.executemany(mysql_string, v_dict.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 3):

beside `MySQLdb.escape_string(SQL)`, pymysql python library also provide `escape_string()` function.

```
>>> import pymysql
>>> pymysql.escape_string("'")
"\\'"
>>>
```

Comment: Does not seem like pymysql has this function.

Answer (score 2):

`MySQLdb.escape_string` is equivalent. All of that is described in [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#id5).