# Escape string Python for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, escaping

I use Python and MySQLdb to download web pages and store them into database. The problem I have is that I can't save complicated strings in the database because they are not properly escaped.

Is there a function in Python that I can use to escape a string for MySQL? I tried with `'''` (triple simple quotes) and `"""`, but it didn't work. I know that PHP has `mysql_escape_string()`, is something similar in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: Do `db_cur.execute('''UPDATE test_table SET field_1="%s" WHERE field_2="%s"''' % (data, condition))` Note the triple single quotes and double quotes around `%s`

Comment: Old thread but shouldn't the last `%` mark in your code be a `,` comma, otherwise it's just the same? @zelusp

Comment: Nope, I think that's right - unless you ran my code and I'm wrong. `% (data, condition)` is taking the variables `data` and `condition` and putting it into the two `%s` placeholders.

Comment: That's just python string formatting, which replaces. If `condition` were, for example, `" or 1 == 1 or" `, for example, you would have a problem. `cur.execute` provides escaping by doing `cur.execute('SOME COMMAND ?', [value])`. `?` is replaced with value.

Answer (score 105):

```
conn.escape_string()
```

See MySQL C API function mapping: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: +1 ... Perfect answer. Surprised to see so many complicated answers out there. Clearly, param'ed queries don't take into account for long strings (text) that is being stored.

Comment: +1 I love the black and white HTML pages with swear words and code.

Comment: _mysql.escape_string("input's " ) can also work to escape an ascii string for mysql. Apparently not for unicode though.  _mysql.escape_string( u"input's éh " )

Comment: What are the parameters for this function?

Comment: our equivalent would be MySQLdb.escape_string("")

Comment: doesnt work... converts string to byte format

Answer (score 85):

The MySQLdb library will actually do this for you, if you use their implementations to build an SQL query string instead of trying to build your own.

Don't do:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_A,COL_B) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (val1, val2)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Do:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_A,COL_B) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (val1, val2))
```

Comment: Somewhat upsetting that it forces quotation marks.  For example, if you were inserting into a conditional table (TABLE_A instead of 'TABLE_A'), you couldn't do it completely with this method.

Comment: bozdoz, this is very much by design as it prevents SQL Injection. If you want to insert into a conditional table, first make sure there is no way a user submitted string can be used for the table name, and then just add it directly to the query.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. Never know what new ways will exist to get around string escaping (Like we currently do over in the PHP world...). Just safer to do prepared statements always

Comment: The builder formats using *exactly the same call* to `db.literal` as `escape` does, so calling it *"safer"* is a bit of a misnomer. Use it because its easier for small queries, but don't be troubled that you're missing something when you have to craft a large query or script by hand.

Comment: Storing Windows file paths as strings in a database column with the '\' separator is useful. Otherwise, when constructing SQL queries directly by interpolation or format strings, you may encounter code issues where you need to use "\\" or "\\\\" depending on the specific context.

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> example = r"""I don't like "special" chars ¯\_(ツ)_/¯"""
>>> example
'I don\'t like "special" chars \xc2\xaf\\_(\xe3\x83\x84)_/\xc2\xaf'
>>> MySQLdb.escape_string(example)
'I don\\\'t like \\"special\\" chars \xc2\xaf\\\\_(\xe3\x83\x84)_/\xc2\xaf'
```

Comment: Hm. Seems as if StackOverflows highlighting algorithm doesn't know Pythons triple quotes.

Comment: This is especially helpful for use in routines where the SQL string is constructed piecemeal.

Comment: MySQLdb fork for Python3: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Answer (score 4):

**Use sqlalchemy's text function to remove the interpretation of special characters:**

Note the use of the function `text("your_insert_statement")` below.  What it does is communicate to sqlalchemy that all of the questionmarks and percent signs in the passed in string should be considered as literals.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime
import re

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://%s:%s@%s/%s"
     % ("your_username", "your_password", "your_hostname_mysql_server:3306",
     "your_database"),
     pool_size=3, pool_recycle=3600)

conn = engine.connect()

myfile = open('access2.log', 'r')
lines = myfile.readlines()

penguins = []
for line in lines:
   elements = re.split('\s+', line)

   print "item: " +  elements[0]
   linedate = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(elements[0]))
   mydate = linedate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

   penguins.append(text(
     "insert into your_table (foobar) values('%%%????')"))

for penguin in penguins:
    print penguin
    conn.execute(penguin)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way to work around this is using something like this when using mysqlclient in python.

suppose the data you want to enter is like this `<ol><li><strong style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Saurav\'s List</strong></li></ol>`. It contains both double qoute and single quote.

You can use the following method to escape the quotes:

> statement = """ Update chats set html='{}' """.format(html_string.replace("'","\\\'"))

Note: three \ characters are needed to escape the single quote which is there in unformatted python string.

Answer (score -3):

install sqlescapy package:

```
pip install sqlescapy
```

then you can escape variables in you raw query

```
from sqlescapy import sqlescape

query = """
    SELECT * FROM "bar_table" WHERE id='%s'
""" % sqlescape(user_input)
```

Comment: Note that sqlescapy doesn't properly escape quotes or double quotes, it simply removes them: https://github.com/elouajib/sqlescapy/blob/master/sqlescapy/sqlescape.py

Answer (score -5):

`{!a}` applies `ascii()` and hence escapes non-ASCII characters like quotes and even emoticons.
Here is an example

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE skcript set author='{!a}',Count='{:d}' where url='{!s}'".format(authors),leng,url))
```

[Python3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: Your Sample Program link is broken, and single quotes are ascii