# Python string formatting UnicodeEncodingError

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script that reads tweets and inserts them into MySQL. Depending on the attributes of each tweet, I need to insert different fields. For that reason, I'm building the fields and values section of the query string as I go, using Python string formatting for convenience:

```
values = """%s, %s, '%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s','%s'""" % (
                url_id, tweet['from_user_id'], conn.escape_string(tweet['location']),
                conn.escape_string(tweet['profile_image_url']),
                tweet['created_at'], tweet['from_user'], tweet['id'],
                conn.escape_string(tweet['text']),
                conn.escape_string(tweet['iso_language_code']), conn.escape_string(tweet['source'])
            )
```

When I do this with tweets that have UTF8 characters, though, I get an error like this:

```
values = """%s, %s, '%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s','%s'""" % (
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 117: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think that the format string (the one with all the "%s"s) is interpreted as ASCII by default, and that's clashing with the UTF-8 characters. I need to keep everything in UTF-8, since this code has to work with any possible language.

So how do I specify that the formatting string is UTF-8? I thought I could change the default encoding for the entire script, but I'm using Python 2.4 and sys.setdefaultencoding doesn't exist in that version. Right now, I'm just not sure how to do that, or if that's even the right thing to do.

Comment: Yeah... that's a [`unicode`, not UTF-8](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

Comment: I hope python3 become status quo soon... Unicode FTW.  BTW py2.4 is too damn old

Comment: Amen to that ... I'm not on 2.4 by choice. All the servers I work on are still stuck on it.

Comment: I also share this problem sometimes... CentOS and RHEL are stuck on 2.4.3... But it's easier to install 3.2 (as python3) than to update to 2.5+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
"""%s, %s, '%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s','%s'"""
```

to:

```
u"""%s, %s, '%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s','%s'"""
```

And then if you want to encode it to UTF-8, do:

```
value.encode('utf8')
```

But it looks like you're using the wrong approach anyway, see [Escape string Python for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I tried that earlier, and I still get the same error. It still tries to encode everything in ASCII.

Comment: No -- good point. Now it's values = u"""%s, %s, '%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s','%s','%s'""" % (
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 81-82: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I knew I was doing something basic that was wrong.