# I'm trying to create a database table for each user who registers. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, database, string

I am trying to work on a login and registration page and I am making a new database and i can do it fine like this:

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons
(
  FirstName varchar(15),
  LastName varchar(15),
  Age int
)";

// Execute query
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

and what I am trying to do is replace the "persons" with a string so that it makes a table but it is dynamic.  I need a string because I am making a table for each user that registers and the new table's name is their username and password send through an md5sum encryption.  I've tried this with no success it wont make a new table like the other one does :

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $data
(
  FirstName varchar(15),
  LastName varchar(15),
  Age int
)";

// Execute query
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Please help me.  I've tried joining strings together with no luck so I need help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to create a row in Persons for each person that registers?

Comment: It's better to use highlight your code and hit the `{ }` button at the top to format it.

Comment: I firmly recommend against this design. All users should be contained in the same table as rows, not as separate tables.

Comment: FWIW I did do a little research on parameterizing database (and table) names way back when in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656636/is-there-any-safe-way-to-parameterize-database-names-in-mysql-queries

Comment: WHY do you want to create a table for each user? There's NO reason to do that.

Comment: @evan.stoddard Wow, very young ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a database table for each user who registers. **What am I doing wrong?**

You are creating a database table for each user who registers.

This is not the way you're supposed to use relational databases. You create a *row* for each new user, not a table. Of course you'll need a few extra columns in your `Persons` table, like the `Password`. I'd also recommend against storing the age because that's not constant. Store the `Birthday` instead.

```sql
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Birthday, Password)
VALUES ('John', 'Smith', '1980-07-21', 'SOME HASH HERE');
```

I hope you don't take it wrong, but you need to slow down a bit and learn more about SQL before trying to write more code. Trust me, it'll be better in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, your were right.  I jumped right into this way to fast.  I think I asked this question when I was 13 and after i learned a lot so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking back at some of the questions I've asked in the past in it's crazy to see how much I've learned in the past few years.