# How can I escape the input to a MySQL db in Python3?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

How can I escape the input to a MySQL db in Python3?
I'm using PyMySQL and works fine, but when I try to do something like:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `Codes` WHERE `ShortCode` =  '{}'".format(request[1]))
```

it won't work if the string has `'` or `"`. I also tried:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `Codes` WHERE `ShortCode` =  %s",request[1])
```

The problem with this is that the library (PyMySQL) uses the formatting syntax for Python2.x, `%`, that doesn't work anymore.
I also found this possible solution

```
conn.escape_string()
```

in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617097/1460016), but I don't know where to add this code.
This is all I got:

```
import pymysql
import sys
conn = pymysql.connect( host   = "localhost",
            user   = "test",
            passwd = "",
            db     = "test")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `Codes` WHERE `ShortCode` =  {}".format(request[1]))

result = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Edit: I solved it! In PyMySQL the right way is like this:

```
import pymysql
import sys
conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
            user="test",
            passwd="",
            db="test")
cursor = conn.cursor()
text = conn.escape(request[1])
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `Codes` WHERE `ShortCode` =  {}".format(text))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Where the `text = conn.escape(request[1])` line is what escapes the code. Found it inside PyMySQL code. There, `request[1]` is the input.

Comment: Cool. You should post the second half of your question as an answer, though. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that button before.

Comment: If solved, then flag your own question as accepted. :-)

Comment: @Jocelyn It tells me "You can accept your own answer in 11 hours", so I'll try later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. In PyMySQL the right way is like this:

```
import pymysql
import sys
conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
            user="test",
            passwd="",
            db="test")
cursor = conn.cursor()
text = conn.escape(request[1])
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `Codes` WHERE `ShortCode` =  {}".format(text))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Where the `text = conn.escape(request[1])` line is what escapes the code. Found it inside PyMySQL code. There, `request[1]` is the input.

Comment: Very bad practice using `.format` directly - @rootsmith's answer is the right way, as it sanitizes.

Answer (score 38):

Although the "solved" answer works, it is not best practice. When using a library conforming to the Python DBI, you should be using bind variables rather than formatting a string and passing it to execute. There are dangers inherent in that methodology.

Therefore, this is the right way to do it:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `Codes` WHERE `ShortCode` = %s", text)
```

Note that this is not a format string but a bind variable passed to the executing cursor.

For details: [Python DBI PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15)

Comment: Note that '%s' should be used even with different types, such as integers. I was trying to use '%d' and got the error: `%d format: a number is required, not str`.

Comment: Tried using this for batch inserts and it ended up doing it a row at a time. Major pain

Answer (score 0):

Ready to use helper function

```
def mysql_insert(conn, table, row):
    cols = ', '.join('`{}`'.format(col) for col in row.keys())
    vals = ', '.join('%({})s'.format(col) for col in row.keys())
    sql = 'INSERT INTO `{0}` ({1}) VALUES ({2})'.format(table, cols, vals)
    conn.cursor().execute(sql, row)
    conn.commit()
```

Usage example

```
insert_into(conn, 'people', {
    'firstname': 'John',
    'lastname': 'Doe',
    'age': 18, })
```

Reference: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/cursors.py#L157-L158

`def execute(self, query, args=None):`

```
If args is a list or tuple, %s can be used as a placeholder in the query.
If args is a dict, %(name)s can be used as a placeholder in the query.
```