# How to avoid SQL injection if I insert data from CSV file with variables in Python3, Pymsql?

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb, sql-injection, pymysql

My ENV is:

MySQL(mariadb) DB Version is 5.5.56

Python3 Version is 3.6

Situation:

I have a telephone statistics CSV file that will generate everyday, and I need to insert those data in my MYSQL DB.

```
Type: Extension Statistic Report,,,,,,,,
From 2018/4/17 上午 12:00:00 To 2018/4/18 上午 12:00:00
Agent Extension: Any number
,,,,,,,,
Agent Extension,,Inbound,,Outbound,,Total,,Total Talking time
,,  Answered,Unanswered,Answered,Unanswered,Answered,Unanswered,
100 MeetingRoom,,0,0,0,0,0,0,00:00:00
101 Build,,0,0,0,0,0,0,00:00:00
102 Lead,,0,0,2.00,1.00,2.00,1.00,01:36:09
103 Discover,,0,0,0,0,0,0,00:00:00
105 Fatto,,1.00,0,28.00,9.00,29.00,9.00,01:07:27
106 Meditare,,0,0,0,0,0,0,00:00:00
Total:,,122.00,41.00,152.00,49.00,274.00,90.00,10h 43m 17s
```

This is my Code:

```
import csv, sys, os
import pymysql
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# DB Config
dbconn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.X.X',
                     port=3306,
                     user='root',
                     passwd='********',
                     db='test',
                     charset='utf8')
cursor = dbconn.cursor()

# Get today's date.
def get_date(d):
    toDay = timedelta(days=d)
    yesDay = datetime.now() + toDay

    return yesDay.strftime("%Y%m%d")

# Get today's str value.
yesterday = get_date(-1)
beforeyesterday = get_date(-2)

with open("/Users/fiona/Downloads/statistics_1704_v1nNHbvGjnIQ2mVwsMLr.csv") as file:
readCSV = csv.reader(file)

extensionCodes = []  # Store extension Number
usersName = []  # Store User Name
inboundsAnswered = []  # Store Inbound Answered
inboundsUnanswered = []  # Store Inbound Unanswered
outboundsAnswered = []  # Store Outbound Answered
outboundsUnanswered = []  # Store Outbound Unanswered
totalsAnswered = []  # Store Total Answered
totalsUnanswered = []  # Store Total Unanswered
totalsTalkingTime = []  # Store Total Talking time

for index, rows in enumerate(readCSV):
    if index not in range(0, 7) and rows[0] != "":
        if str(rows[0])[:3] != "Tot":
            extensionCode = str(rows[0])[:3] # Store every rows extension number
        elif str(rows[0])[:5] == "Total":
            break

        userName = rows[0] # Store every rows name
        inboundAnswered = float(rows[2])
        inboundUnanswered = float(rows[3])
        outboundAnswered = float(rows[4])
        outboundUnanswered = float(rows[5])
        totalAnswered = float(rows[6])
        totalUnanswered = float(rows[7])
        totalTalkingTime = rows[8]

        sql = """
            INSERT INTO 
                test (extension_number, username, inbound_answered, inbound_unanswered, 
                outbound_answered, outbound_unanswered, total_answered, total_unanswered, 
                total_talking_time, createtime)
            VALUES
                (%d, %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %s, %s); 
        """ % (int(extensionCode), "'"+userName+"'", int(inboundAnswered), int(inboundUnanswered),
               int(outboundAnswered), int(outboundUnanswered), int(totalAnswered),
               int(totalUnanswered), "'"+totalTalkingTime+"'", yesterday)

        print(sql) # Testing SQL Syntax
        cursor.execute(sql)


dbconn.commit()
cursor.close()
dbconn.close()
```

Using above code I can insert my data into DB, but I also want to save the SQL injection problem. So I have done some research and change my code, but still can not successful.

1. [Python best practice and securest to connect to MySQL and execute queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929364/python-best-practice-and-securest-to-connect-to-mysql-and-execute-queries/7929438#7929438)
2. [How can I escape the input to a MySQL db in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363335/how-can-i-escape-the-input-to-a-mysql-db-in-python3)
3. [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)
4. [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries)

Now, I known if I want to avoid SQL injection, I can not use `%` to get my variable values, I have to use `,` to get values.
But, I find out that using `,` seems the values will become **str** that make my %d will failed.

My DB Design is like:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr57r.jpg)

Is there anyone who can give me some advice or direction?
Thank you for your help!

**Update 1:**

if I use reference 4.

```
sql = """
    INSERT INTO test (extension_number, username, inbound_answered, inbound_unanswered, outbound_answered, outbound_unanswered, total_answered, total_unanswered, 
                total_talking_time, createtime)
            VALUES (%d, %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %s, %s)
        """, (int(extensionCode), userName, int(inboundAnswered), int(inboundUnanswered), int(outboundAnswered), int(outboundUnanswered),
              int(totalAnswered), int(totalUnanswered), totalTalkingTime, yesterday)
```

it will shows:

```
packet = prelude + sql[:packet_size-1]
TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes
('\n                INSERT INTO test (extension_number, username, inbound_answered, inbound_unanswered, \n                    outbound_answered, outbound_unanswered, total_answered, total_unanswered, \n                    total_talking_time, createtime)\n                VALUES (%d, %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %s, %s)\n            ', (100, 'MeetingRoom', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '00:00:00', '20180423'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Update 2:**

I tried another way,

```
sql = "INSERT INTO test (extension_number, username, inbound_answered, inbound_unanswered, " \
"outbound_answered, outbound_unanswered, total_answered, total_unanswered, total_talking_time, " \
"createtime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", \
     (int(extensionCode), userName, int(inboundAnswered), int(inboundUnanswered),
      int(outboundAnswered), int(outboundUnanswered), int(totalAnswered),
      int(totalUnanswered), totalTalkingTime, yesterday)

cursor.execute(sql)
```

but, still not working

```
   packet = prelude + sql[:packet_size-1]
   TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes
```

**Update 3:**

Finally, I find out the way,

```
sql = "INSERT INTO test (extension_number, username, inbound_answered, " \
              "inbound_unanswered, outbound_answered, outbound_unanswered, " \
              "total_answered, total_unanswered, total_talking_time, createtime) " \
              "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
data = (extensionCode, userName, inboundAnswered, inboundUnanswered,
                outboundAnswered, outboundUnanswered, totalAnswered,
                totalUnanswered, totalTalkingTime, yesterday)

cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

So, It seems like if I want to use variable in cursor.execute(), I have to separate the sql syntax and value.

If I want to use sql syntax and value in one line, I have to use cursor.execute(sql syntax and value) directly and double quotes or triple quotes are both fine.

such as:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (extension_number, username, inbound_answered, inbound_unanswered, 
            outbound_answered, outbound_unanswered, total_answered, total_unanswered, total_talking_time, 
            createtime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                  (extensionCode, userName, inboundAnswered, inboundUnanswered, outboundAnswered, outboundUnanswered, totalAnswered, totalUnanswered, totalTalkingTime, yesterday))
```

separate sql syntax and values or just put them all together in cursor.execute which one is more security?

Thank you for your advice, let me find the right direction!

Comment: I don't understand why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries doesn't answer your question . It is the exact solution to your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries)

Comment: @DeepSpace
it will shows 

packet = prelude + sql[:packet_size-1]

TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes

('\n                INSERT INTO test (extension_number, username, inbound_answered, inbound_unanswered, \n                    outbound_answered, outbound_unanswered, total_answered, total_unanswered, \n                    total_talking_time, createtime)\n                VALUES (%d, %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %s, %s)\n            ', (100, 'MeetingRoom', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '00:00:00', '20180423'))

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Because you are doing it wrong. Read the answer to the duplicated question I marked.

Comment: separate sql syntax and values or just put them all together in cursor.execute which is more security?