# Wrong sql syntax because of single or double quote in string

Tags: python, mysql

```
sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO users_time_zone (user_id, email, username, gcm_reg_id, time_zone) " \
                  "VALUES(%s, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gcm_reg_id ='%s', id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) " % \
                  (user_data['user_id'], user_data['email'], user_data['username'],
                   user_data['gcm_reg_id'], user_data['time_zone'], user_data['gcm_reg_id'])
            print sql
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
```

some times username is like dinda_a'yunin or dinda_a"yunin which makes sql like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO users_time_zone (user_id, email, username, gcm_reg_id, time_zone) VALUES(4298849, 'dinda_a'yunin@yahoo.com', 'dinda_ayunin', 'APA91bGRvg74', 'Asia/Jakarta') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gcm_reg_id ='APA91bGRvg74', id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

That makes wrong syntax is there anyway to solve that

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable towards [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations) here...

You either want to use [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html):

```
sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO users_time_zone (user_id, email, username, gcm_reg_id, time_zone) " \
      "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gcm_reg_id =%s, id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) " 

data = (user_data['user_id'], user_data['email'], user_data['username'],
        user_data['gcm_reg_id'], user_data['time_zone'], user_data['gcm_reg_id'])

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

Or [escape data manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617097/1149736):

```
data = list(conn.escape_string, data)

sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO users_time_zone (user_id, email, username, gcm_reg_id, time_zone) " \
      "VALUES(%s, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gcm_reg_id ='%s', id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) "\
        % data
```

Comment: I am still getting same error
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dinda_a\\'yunin@yahoo.com'', ''dinda_ayunin'', ''APA91bGRvg74L3Z5mNzGYq8TwQiur99T' at line 1")

Comment: @JayPrakash I forgot that `escape_string` adds also quotes around the string, updated my answer to reflect that (just remove `'`' from around `%s`) and it should work.