# TypeError: escape_string() argument 1 (impossible<bad format char>) in Python

Tags: python

I want to escape a string in MySQL query because string is creating problems for me. I am using MySQLdb and to escape a string I am using `MySQLdb.escape_string("'")` but that is giving the error.
Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? Or how should this string be escaped properly?

**Code**

```
import MySQLdb

def database():
    global db
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="user", passwd="sss",db="database_name")

database()
cursor = db.cursor()
var = "some's name"
MySQLdb.escape_string("'")
query = "select * from node Where io = '{}' ".format(var)
cursor.execute(query)
value = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Desktop/practise.py", line 30, in <module>
  MySQLdb.escape_string("'")

TypeError: escape_string() argument 1 (impossible bad format char>)
```

Comment: It looks like MySQLdb.escape_string("'") is expecting a char. Have you tired MySQLdb.escape_string(') or MySQLdb.escape_string(\')

Comment: yes that will give you syntax error

Comment: Maybe this question can help you out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql/27575399)

Comment: getting this error TypeError: escape_string() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)