# How to fix 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'escape_string'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I'm new to python. Previously I used PHP with MySQL; now learning python. At this point, I'm learning to work with MySQL.

I have connected to the database using the code bellow:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="myUser", password="myPass", host="localhost", database="myDb")
```

The connection seems to work properly and I can query items from the database using the "cursor":

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM..."

cnx.cursor.execute(sql)
```

The problem is, when I use the "escape_string" method of the connection like bellow:

```
escaped_string = cnx.escape_string("some SQL invalid 'terms'")
```

I get :

```
AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'escape_string'.
```

I thought it's a bug related to the mysql_connector, so I thought updating may help.

`pip install --upgrade mysql_connector`

This updated mysql_connector but didn't solve the problem.

I'm using **python 3.7.1** and **mysql_connector 2.1.6**

Comment: I know nothing about Python but, in general, string escaping is an obsolete technique that's very popular in programming tutorials. The proper way to inject external input is to use prepared statements (and it's also easier and more concise).

Comment: A pointer: per the docs, `escape_string` is a method of the `MySQL` class (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-escape-string.html), not of the `MySQLConnection` class (whose methods are listed at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection.html). I don't know the library well enough to advise any further than that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález You're right. It's the better approach.However, I saw few examples using escape_string on connection and wanted to try myself and got confused when found it not working in my code. So, raised the question.

Comment: @MarkAmery You found i! This is the right reason. I might have messed up myself between the mysql.connector and MySQLdb api.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find out why this is happening to you, but you can create your own `escape_string` using python.
Don't do:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_A,COL_B) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (val1, val2)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Do:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_A,COL_B) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (val1, val2))
```

You can follow these links to find out more solutions:
[Escape string Python for MySQL](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/37311c) and
[Escape string Python for MySQL _ Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql)

Comment: I have reviewed them already. The reason has been pointed out by MarkAmery. I've found your guideline to be great and will be following for sure. Thanks.