# How to properly parameterize query and escape inputs properly to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm using mysqlclient (fork of MySQLdb1 for python3) in Python 3.4.3, and according to what I've read online ([Escape string Python for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql#answer-27575399)), MySQLdb Python queries should be written like this for proper escaping:

```
query = self.conn.cursor()
query.execute('SELECT 1 FROM servers WHERE ip=%s AND port=%s AND game_id=%s' ,(ip,port,gameid))
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, I get the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple' mysqldb

This appears to work, but this could lead to SQL injection?

```
query = self.conn.cursor()
query.execute("SELECT 1 FROM servers WHERE ip='%s' AND port=%s AND game_id='%s'" % (ip,port,gameid))
```

So, how do I safely get the query above to work using the preferred syntax method that will escape it all for me in Python 3.4.3?

Comment: So far I know "Parameterized query and Prepared Statement"  are the best way to prevent sql injection with python. You are in the right direction in my opinion. See [this](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/) for more.

Comment: Please show the full traceback, and the values of `ip`, `port` and` gameid`. Note that as you suspect, you must never ever use your second code.

Comment: ip `68.232.163.47` port `12203` gameid `mohaa` - couldn't get it to work unless I used the bad way... it would always give me that `unsupported operand types` error.

Comment: Maybe I just need to convert those params to strs?  `str(ip), str(port), str(gameid)`?

Comment: Nope. that didn't work.  I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get mysqlclient (a fork of MySQLdb) https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/ to work with Python 3.4 with the proper SQL syntax (the syntax that escapes everything for you).  I switched to mysql-connector, and the same query code now works fine.  It looks like a bug in mysqlclient.

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/

Answer (score 0):

mysqlclient-python doesn't support Python 3.4 anymore.
Use newer Python.