# Why does this query work in mysql workbench and not when I run it in python

Tags: python, mysql

I created a query in MySQL workbench to test out using MySQL in python, it runs fine in workbench, but when I run it in python, it tells me the part after the WHERE is invalid syntax

I have looked around for this issue and cannot find it, python MySQL works for most queries I have run but this one is failing and I do not know why

code:

```
import math
import mysql.connector

config = {'user': 'allazzanni', 'password': 'not posting that here', 'host': 'also no', 'database': 'i could, but i wont'}


def queryDatabase (query):

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    cursor.execute(query) #this is where the error is do stuff with the result

query = ("SELECT g.Grade FROM Grade = g, Topic = t WHERE g.idTopic = t.idTopic and t.nameTopic = %s")

print queryDatabase (query, 'math')
```

```
Expected:
the query to execute properly

Actual:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'g.idTopic = t.idTopic and t.nameTopic = 'math'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this

```
query = ("SELECT g.Grade FROM Grade = g, Topic = t WHERE g.idTopic = t.idTopic and t.nameTopic = %s")

print queryDatabase (query, 'math')
```

Can you do this ?

```
query = ("""SELECT g.Grade FROM Grade = g, Topic = t WHERE g.idTopic = t.idTopic and t.nameTopic = '{0}'""".format('math'))

print queryDatabase (query)
```

What you are trying to do is sending the query as is, and sending the query param as a separate param to your `queryDatabase` function, which is only expecting one param (`query`). Hence you need to perform string interpolation before you pass the `query` to your function.

Hope this resolves your query.

**Update:**

It seems that it is happening because strings are not being escaped properly. Can you please follow some of the answers that are mentioned here : [Escape string Python for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql)

Thanks

Comment: tried that but it still does the same error, I don't think the issue is with how I am passing it, but rather with the syntax of the SQL itself, but I have no idea why it is giving me these problems since it works in workbench

Comment: Just updated the query - can you please try it ? I have used triple quotes to escape strings

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use string interpolation or concatenation to put parameter values into query strings that you send to your database. Not only does that introduce a vulnerability to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, it may also require awkward quotes and quote escapes in the SQL string, as you have experienced yourself.
Every DB API 2 compliant driver package supports parameter binding and that's what you should *always* use to put parameters into your query.

You can pass the query parameters to your function using Python's [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

```
def queryDatabase (query, *args):
    # every positional argument passed in after the 'query' argument will be collected in 'args'
    # in this example, 'args' will be ('math',). This is a valid format for the 'params' 
    # argument of the 'execute' method
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)    
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    # passing the tuple containing the positional arguments as 'params' argument to 'execute' 
    cursor.execute(query, args)
    return cursor.fetchall()

query = "SELECT g.Grade FROM Grade = g, Topic = t WHERE g.idTopic = t.idTopic and t.nameTopic = %s"
# the parameters must be provided in the order matching the markers in your query string
print queryDatabase (query, 'math')
```

Disclaimer: I do not have a MySQL DB to test this. I tested with `sqlite3` and Sybase ASE via `pypyodbc`. The recipe worked for both engines.
Using a query without parameter markers and omitting any positional arguments worked as well, e.g.:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Grade"
print queryDatabase (query)
```

I'm fairly positive that this will work the same way for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Bind Variables,
Try to write it like that:

```
query = ("""SELECT g.Grade FROM Grade = g, Topic = t WHERE g.idTopic = t.idTopic and t.nameTopic = :s""")

print queryDatabase (query, {s='math'})
```

The triple dock-strings is instead of using "text" which allows you to use bind variables.
Now you can add add many as you want to the dictionary, notice the syntax - you need to add ":" before the argument.