# Parameterized Table Population

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to populate a table(whose name is parameterized). The program runs fine, up until the point where the command gets executed.
Here is the code:

```
table_name = input("Enter table name: ")
value_name = input("Enter name: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (name) VALUES (%s)" % db.escape_string(table_name), (value_name)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

I get the following error: 
`TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help. Have a great rest of the day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an alternative you good go with the new formatting format

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO {tab} (name) VALUES ({val})".format(tab=db.escape_string(table_name), 
                                                        val=value_name)
```

or

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO {db.escape_string(table_name)} (name) VALUES ({value_name})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the sql formatting like below and try.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (name) VALUES (%s)" % (db.escape_string(table_name), value_name)
```

Comment: I tried it and I get the following error:
```AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'escape_string'
```

Comment: You may want to do escape with `connection` object. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql.