# Python adds single quote to my query parameters

Tags: python, mysql, quotes, pymysql

I'm trying to execute thi query:

```
SELECT '23.34.67.0/22' CONCAT(DAY_31, 'hello') DAY_31 FROM Jule
```

using pymysql. My code is:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT %s CONCAT(%s, %s) %s FROM Jule", (p, 'DAY_' + _day, as_tmp, 'DAY_' + _day))
```

But python adds single quote and return a syntax error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('DAY_31', 'hello') 'DAY_31' FROM Jule' at line 1"

DAY_31 is a column of Jule Schema

Comment: Did you check string escaping? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql) question point you in the right direction? What I mean by string escaping is that there seems to be an automatic unwanted escaping done on your string and there might be a way to avoid that in the cursor.execute func.

Comment: it returns "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('\\'DAY_31\\'', '6762') '\\'DAY_31\\'' FROM Jule' at line 1"

Comment: ok, a comma missing 'cursor.execute("SELECT %s, CONCAT(%s, %s) %s FROM Jule", (p, 'DAY_' + _day, as_tmp, 'DAY_' + _day))

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `SELECT '23.34.67.0/22', CONCAT(DAY_31, 'hello'), DAY_31 FROM Jule`, i.e. aren't you missing commas?

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, `?` in place of `%s` might do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it returns 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you end up with quotes is because `cursor.execute` adds these around values you pass in as arguments. This is totally appropriate for your second argument, because if the value 'hello' was inserted into the query as-is you would end up with a query like this:

```
 SELECT '23.34.67.0/22' CONCAT(DAY_31, hello) DAY_31 FROM Jule
```

and you would have errors telling you that MySQL can't identify what `hello` should refer to.

Obviously though, this is not appropriate for situations where you want to pass in **field names**, or any other part of the query that is not a primitive string value. In these cases, you will need to splice them into your string before executing the query. One way you could do that is with [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), but there are other alternatives as well. Here's your `cursor.execute` line with the field names spliced in using f-strings:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT %s, CONCAT({'DAY_'+_day}, %s) {'DAY_'+_day} FROM Jule", (p, as_tmp))
```

Notice that I've removed the `'DAY_'+_day` from the arguments list as well.

**Important note:**

While this should work like this (although I think you also needed an extra comma after `SELECT '23.34.67.0/22'`, which I've added in the example above), it's very important that if `day` has a value that originates from outside of your application (e.g. passed in by a user in a form field) that you make sure it is exactly in the format you want before splicing it in to your query. [Checking that the string value is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267145/1506086) could be one way to do that. The reason that it is important is that without this, your application could be prone to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), which would potentially allow users to run arbitrary SQL on your database. If the value of `day` is calculated solely by your application, you shouldn't need to worry about this.

Answer (score -1):

Actually what is happening has nothing to do with `cursor.execute`. It is just the way you are formatting the string in python.

We should first note that %s %d can be specific to SQL, and that these can also be used in python for string formatting.

So taking this into account, I think you have no need to use %s for string formatting (which on top does not help with readability). And since you are `cursor.execute`ing straight to your database, you could format your string straight away in python.

Small check to see whats happening:

```
p = "23.34.67.0/22"
as_tmp = "hello"
_day = "3"
print("SELECT %s CONCAT(%s, %s) %s FROM Jule", (p, 'DAY_' + _day, as_tmp, 'DAY_' + _day))
# output
# SELECT %s CONCAT(%s, %s) %s FROM Jule ('23.34.67.0/22', 'DAY_3', 'hello', 'DAY_3')
# ^^^^ so this is what is being sent in cursor.execute (with all the quotes and so on)
```

If you format with an f-string you will increase readability, and you should get rid of your problem with the quotes

```
print(f"SELECT '{p}' CONCAT(DAY_{_day}, '{as_tmp}') DAY_{_day} FROM Jule")
# output
# SELECT '23.34.67.0/22' CONCAT(DAY_3, 'hello') DAY_3 FROM Jule
```

So the solution could be:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT '{p}' CONCAT(DAY_{_day}, '{as_tmp}') DAY_{_day} FROM Jule")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem was a missing comma. Anyway I'll keep in mind your answer

Comment: This answer leaves the application prone to SQL injection if `as_tmp` could originate from outside the application. The original approach was fine for string data values, but there's no way of avoiding splicing in field names like you suggested.