# Python: Escape Single Quote from MySQL Query

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, mysql-python

I have a query string that runs in side a loop and for every item in the list query gets executed. The list contains strings and I use python string format technique to replace the query with the respective string from the list as iteration progress.

I have unicoded the query along with the string from the list: Here is my unicoded query:

```
query = ur'''SELECT something FROM some_table WHERE some_name LIKE "{this_name}%"'''
```

Prior to execute I encode the query string to `utf-8`

```
            try:
                formatted_query = query.format(this_name=list_name)
                #encode the query
                encoded_q = formatted_query.encode('utf-8')
                # execute the query
                self.dbCursor.execute(encoded_q)
                row = self.dbCursor.fetchone()
            except Exception, e:
                traceback.print_exc()
```

But the problem is that sometimes I run into strings from list that has single quote example: `foo's`. I have already unicoded with utf-8 and I thought doing so I don't have to worry about situations like this. But I am getting sql error since MySQL is not skipping the single quote.

My next attempt was to replace the single quote:

```
format_string = u"foo's".replace(u"'",u"\'")
```

But this didn't work either. I also saw that answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561178/python-equivalent-of-mysql-real-escape-string-for-getting-strings-safely-into-m) is using mysqldb library inbuilt functionality which I am not aware of, so I seek the help from stackoverflow community to solve this problem.

I change the code to reflect the solution suggested in answers but result is the same: Here is the change:

```
args = [u"{this_name}%".format(this_name=format_name)]
self.dbCursor.execute(query.encode('utf-8'), args)
```

*#error get thrown at this line:*

**Error:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u014d' in position 4: ordinal not in range(256)
```

This is the string that error is complaining and I have checked the type of that string its a unicoded string.

```
this_name= Sentōkisei type= <type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the raw flag?

Comment: didn't really understand what you meant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `dbCursor.execute` with two arguments, your DB adapter will quote the arguments for you.  See the [DB-API specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) for details:

```
query = u'''SELECT something FROM some_table WHERE some_name LIKE %s'''
args = [u"{this_name}%".format(this_name=list_name)]
self.dbCursor.execute(query, args)
```

The `%s` in `query` is a [parameter marker](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). It will be replaced by a quoted parameter given in `args`. The correct parameter marker to use depends on your DB adapter. For example, [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) uses `%s`, while [oursql](http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/) and [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) use `?`.

Using parametrized SQL is the recommended way. You really should never have to quote the arguments yourself.

---

Regarding the error, you post that

```
this_name= Sentōkisei type= <type 'unicode'>
```

I am going to assume this means `format_name` is unicode. Therefore,

```
args = [u"{this_name}%".format(this_name=format_name)]
```

will make `args` a list containing one unicode.

Now we reach the line which is raising an error:

```
self.dbCursor.execute(query.encode('utf-8'), args)
```

`query` is already `unicode`. If you encode that unicode, then it becomes a `str`. So `query.encode('utf-8')` is a `str`, but `args` is a list of `unicode`. I'm not sure why you wanted to encode `query`, but your DB adapter should be able to take two unicode arguments. So try

```
self.dbCursor.execute(query, args)
```

Now, upon re-reading your comments, it appears you've tried this and it also raises the same error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u014d' in position 75: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I'm not sure why the DB adapter is trying to encode the unicode with `latin-1` when you want `utf-8` instead. The best solution would be to track down where this choice of `latin-1` is coming from.

A hacky workaround would be to try encoding the strings yourself:

```
query = u'''SELECT something FROM some_table WHERE some_name LIKE %s'''.encode('utf-8')
args = [u"{this_name}%".format(this_name=list_name).encode('utf-8')]
self.dbCursor.execute(query, args)
```

But let me stress I really don't think this is the best way, nor should this be necessary.

Comment: so, I don't need to do this: `encoded_q = formatted_query.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: Regarding Unicode, I think that `"{this_name}%"` needs to be replaced with `u"{this_name}%"`.

Comment: I think so because with the suggested solution I get the fallowing: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
because I have to deal with strings like this  Hój type= <type 'unicode'> but I check for the type and I have unicoded it prior to this.

Comment: @unutbu actually I ran my code with your solution and compared with mine to see where they fail they both fail at the same string: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u014d' in position 75: ordinal not in range(256) format_strange_user= Sentōkisei type= <type 'unicode'>` I also did small alteration to your code but that really didn't make any difference I think. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Please post the revised code you are running, and the full traceback error message. It will tell us, among other things, exactly what line is generating the error.

Comment: @unbutu nothing has change I added your solution but no improvement `self.dbCursor.execute(user_id_query.encode('utf-8'), args)` this is the line.

Comment: @unutbu I have added the error to the question along with the your suggestion.

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon: Could you post the `mysql` output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE some_table`? I wonder if the table is set to use the `latin-1` character set. I'm not familiar with the mysql-python DB adapter. You might want to check what is the proper way to configure the adapter to use `utf-8` encoding by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an answer to a similar question here, you can take a look at it too!

link :https://stackoverflow.com/a/61042304/8939258

Answer (score 0):

I give up on escaping it. Instead, I replace the single quote with a wild card which is `%`

```
text = "woman's"
text = text.replace("'","%")
```

It works perfectly in the mysql