# ERROR: Python equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string, for getting strings safely into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I understand from the following post that Python equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string can be tested using two lines of code that can be found on the following stack link.  I can not get the desired output so I figured I would reopen the discussion for help on my isolated matter.

Related stack overflow link:

[Python equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string, for getting strings safely into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561178/python-equivalent-of-mysql-real-escape-string-for-getting-strings-safely-into-m)

Why would those two lines of code work for someone but not on my machine?

```
root@dev:~# python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02)
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.escape_string("'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be impossible<bad format char>, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer in that first question could not be more wrong. You should just be using the builtin parameter passing argument to the DB api.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO candidate (name, address) VALUES  (?,?)",
                (v_dict['name'], v_dict['address']))
```

It will safely escape the parameters for you.

Comment: Why do you think I am getting that error though?  It will not accept the string!

Comment: no idea, it's a wrapper around a C function, and the [mysql dev documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-escape-string.html) says 'Do not use this function', so....

Comment: I am not using that function!  I am using real_escape_string.  Call me crazy but the MySQLdb User's Guide http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html states that mysql_real_escape_string() =  conn.escape_string()