# how to INSERT a HTML formatted text to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am creating a database and inserting data. our backend engineer said he need a column to save whole articles with HTML format. But when I am inserting data it gives me an error like this:

[image]

and I check the exact where the error comes from, I found:

[image]

looks like this part has some quote or punctuation issues, and the same line occurs multiple times. And I use `str()` function to convert the formatted HTML text(use `type()` to see the datatype is `bs4.element.Tag`) to string, but the problem still exists.

My database description is:

```
('id', 'mediumint(9)', 'NO', 'PRI', None, 'auto_increment')
('weburl', 'varchar(200)', 'YES', '', None, '')
('picurl', 'varchar(200)', 'YES', '', None, '')
('headline', 'varchar(200)', 'YES', '', None, '')
('abstract', 'varchar(200)', 'YES', '', None, '')
('body', 'longtext', 'YES', '', None, '')
('formed', 'longtext', 'YES', '', None, '')
('term', 'varchar(50)', 'YES', '', None, '')
```

And the function I used to collect full text is:

```
def GetBody(url,plain=False):
    # Fetch the html file
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html_doc = response.read()

    # Parse the html file
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

    #find the article body
    body = soup.find("section", {"name":"articleBody"})

    if not plain:
        return body
    else:
        text = ""
        for p_tag in body.find_all('p'):
            text = ' '.join([text,p_tag.text])
        return text
```

And I import the data by this function:

```
 def InsertDatabase(section):
        s = TopStoriesSearch(section)
            count1 = 0
        formed = []
        while count1 < len(s):
    #         tr = GetBody(s[count1]['url'])
    #         formed.append(str(tr))
    #         count1 = count1 + 1
(I use this to convert HTML to string, or use the code below)
              formed.append(GetBody(s[count1]['url']))
              count1 = count1 + 1
```

and this is my insert function:

```
for each in overall(I save everything in this list named overall):
          cur.execute('insert into topstories(formed) values("%s")' % (each["formed"]))
```

Any tips to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you try `cur.execute('insert into topstories(formed) values(%(formed)s)', each)`?

Comment: The observed behavior is a symptom of SQL Injection vulnerability. A value incorporated into the text of a SQL statement is *not* safe for inclusion. Best practice is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders. If that's not possible, values must be properly escaped. MySQL real_escape_string function is purpose built to perform the proper escaping. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html   mysql-python provides equivalent function  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561178/python-equivalent-of-mysql-real-escape-string-for-getting-strings-safely-into-m

Comment: The link to the stackoverflow question in the previous comment... please refer to the answer from Alex Martelli (and not just the accepted answer).

Comment: @spencer7593 Hey, I use `MySQLdb.escape_string(each['formed'])` , but it shows `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Tag'`.

Comment: @Mehmed Looks like it still does not work...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `execute()` function is as follows ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)):

```
cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)
```

Therefore, you can provide values to be used in the query as an argument to the `execute()` function. In that case, it will handle values automatically, eliminating your problem:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(...)
cur = cnx.cursor()
...
for each in overall:
    # If 'each' is a dictionary containing 'formed' as key,
    # i.e. each = {..., 'formed': ..., ...}, you can do as follows
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO topstories(formed) VALUES (%s)', (each['formed']))
    # You can also use dictionary directly if you use named placeholder in the query
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO topstories(formed) VALUES (%(formed)s)', each)
...
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```